# SSH Tunnel - finding port forwarding on the remote side

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have ec2 connected via SSH with tunnel from port 1993 on local to port 9999 on remote.
The problem is that if 9999 is occupied I want to change dynamically the port forwarding rule to be from 1993 on local to 10000 on remote for example. I also have no intention of letting the client to mess around with the port forwarding. Thus, I want to change the port on the remote side. Meaning that if the client has a tunnel from 1993 to 9999 he will now have a tunnel from 1993 to 10000, and the client won't know about it nor he should do anything about it.
I looked over the internet where can I find the forwarding rules on the remote side - some sort of config file like sshd.config that contains all the forwarding rules but I couldn't find anything.
Is there a simple answer or should I reconsider?

Comment: What do you mean by "port 9999 on remote"? The forwarding rule will send traffic to a destination server (which could be localhost) and a destination port. It does not control the _source_ port from which the traffic is coming. Same thing with your own computer -- for example, when you SSH to an instance, you are connecting to the destination server's port 22, but your request is coming from a _random port_ on your computer. What is the _actual_ problem that you are trying to solve? Why can't you connect to the destination server correctly?

Comment: I'm trying to run a number of jupyter lab concurrently. The users will use SSH tunnel to the ports of the server. If one port is occupied(taken) then I want to "fix" the tunnel, and change the destination port accordingly.

Comment: You'll need to invent your own system for doing that.